# "RuntimeError: invalid slot offset" on trying to run python package

Tags: python, macos, spyder

I use the `pyhyphen` package for a script I run all the time. Recently, I updated to MacOS Big Sur. Spyder was laggy, but I fixed that by running a virtual environment and `pip install`ing what I needed. No issues.

Now, when I try to run `from hyphen import Hyphenator` ([here is the package page](https://pypi.org/project/PyHyphen/#id3)), I get the following error:

```
[autoreload of hyphen.dictools failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/extensions/autoreload.py", line 245, in check
    superreload(m, reload, self.old_objects)
  File "/Users/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/extensions/autoreload.py", line 394, in superreload
    module = reload(module)
  File "/Users/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 314, in reload
    return importlib.reload(module)
  File "/Users/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 159, in reload
    raise ImportError(msg.format(parent_name),
ImportError: parent 'hyphen' not in sys.modules
]


runcell(0, '/Users/myname/Documents/project/project.py')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/myname/Documents/project/project.py", line 17, in <module>
    from hyphen import Hyphenator

  File "/Users/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hyphen/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .hyphenator import Hyphenator

  File "/Users/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hyphen/hyphenator.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import hnj

RuntimeError: invalid slot offset
```

The `from hyphen import Hyphenator` is the only line in the script. I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling the package six hundred times - and I cannot find any kind of solution for `invalid slot offset`. All other packages import fine, no issues.

Spyder (in Anaconda) is running python version 3.8.5. I have non-anaconda 3.9 installed, but I can't imagine that has any effect since I'm running spyder in a virtual environment.

Comment: it will be difficult to help without knowing what is in project.py. It will be not a spyder problem thought

Comment: @user3732793 not much in `project.py` besides some basic `pandas` data manipulation, the `random` package, and the `pyhyphen` errors

Comment: Can you reproduce the same error when you create a new conda environment from scratch and you create a blank project with that single line?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco - just did - new blank env, one line script in new blank project - same offset error

Comment: Could you verify that the library is installed at the correct path? This could be related to a non-compatible version being loaded by Python.

Answer (score 1):

it seems the problem when installing the package .in this line of code from setup.py

```
ext_modules=[
        Extension('hyphen.hnj', ['lib/hnjmodule.c',
                                 'lib/hyphen.c',
                                 'lib/hnjalloc.c'],
                  include_dirs=['lib'],
                  py_limited_api=True)
                  ],
```

the package hnj is not compiled correctely

try to installe nd build the package manually

Comment: So I tried this - and still got the same errors. Do you mean install and build the `hyphen.hnj` or the `pyhyphen` package itself?

Comment: try to get pyhyphen from github then install it using python3 setup.py install to see if there are errors

Comment: Got the package, unzipped, ran the `python3 setup.py install` - no errors. Still same error in the script when run. Maybe the download takes a minute to propagate to Anaconda itself?

Comment: copy the module folder to your project folder then try to build it like this python setup.py build_ext -i this will build it in place ,you have to test the extensio in the same directory in this case

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to install via `anaconda`, not `pip`:

```
source /Users/myname/anaconda3/bin/activate
conda install -c auto pyhyphen
```

Comment: I wish, doesn't work/find that package in any of the anaconda channels. Get this: `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:` - would be nice, but alas